# How big is Ego's brain?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

As Ego claimed that his planetary form is much larger than Earth and the Moon, how exactly big was Ego's brain protected in the core beneath the planetary cavern?

Comment: Based on the moment when Baby Groot plants the bomb, I'd estimate the brain as being not much more than three metres wide.  Which seems kind of small.

Comment: The Celestial shown during the first Infinity Stone scene in `Guardians of the Galaxy (Vol 1)` looks about the right size to support a ~3m wide brain.

Comment: He said his planet was _smaller_ then moon.

Answer (score 3):

## Roughly 9 feet.

We don't have an exact measurement (and it would be extremely difficult to obtain one), but this image offers a nice opportunity to compare it to Baby Groot.

[image]

From front to back, the brain is roughly 11 Baby Groots long. How tall is Baby Groot? According to [this site](https://www.bleedingcool.com/2016/12/17/finally-life-size-guardians-galaxy-2-baby-groot-toy-preorder/), Baby Groot is 10 inches tall. 10 inches times 11 is roughly 9 feet. So @Tim's estimate is spot on.